# Populating catalogs in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, insert, google-cloud-datastore, populate

I'm new using Google App Engine and I want to pre-populate catalogs before to go production.

Catalogs like:
- Role (role_key,role_description)
- Country (county_key,description)
- etc.

If I was using mySQl, oracle, etc. like my data store and not using GAE I would do something like:

- insert into Role (role_key,role_description) values (1,'ADMIN');
- insert into Role (role_key,role_description) values (2,'USER_VIEW');
- insert into Country (county_key,role_description) values ('MX','Mexico');
- insert into Country (county_key,role_description) values ('USA','United states');
- etc

And before to deploy my application I'd run this script into the data base.

But how can I do this (maybe not exactly the same, not same sintax, etc) with Google App Engine?

Thank you people.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

The general solution for this is [the bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html). You can use it to import data from a CSV file or other formatted data source.

For more ad-hoc data insertion, there's also [remote_api](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html). This will give you an interactive shell where you can manage datastore entities or make other API calls.

Comment: Also, for largely static, small datasets like this, you could simply not store it in the datastore in the first place - load it into memory instead!

Comment: Ok, I'll try with the remote_api for java. Thanx.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with repote_api for java. Thanx